# Solid viewport shading in edit mode is transparent in places?

Tags: modeling

Limit selection to visible is on! This is driving me bonkers. I hit a button somewhere and now my mesh is like this in edit mode:

[image]

Note: it's fine in object mode.

Please help! :-(

edit: i meant limit selection to visible IS on lol

Comment: The issue was the maximum clipping value! Thanks so much! Should I delete this question if it's a duplicate or.. ?

Comment: Glad it worked :) It's not necessary, duplicates are necessarily bad. They provide more search terms (provided the questions aren't *too* similar, but I don't think this the case here) which lead to the answer, making it easier for others to find.